# Are there any built-in LoopBack features for handling a TCP connection?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I'm working on [LoopBack](https://loopback.io/)-application with purpose to arrange process of storing set of metrics gathered from GPS-devices, which are designed to communicate with server over TCP/IP. The protocol of data exchange is predefined and it is binary so I can't benefit from advantages given by LoopBack to setup data gathering.

It's impossible to use [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) as in [example](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Realtime-socket-io.html) because of its high-level nature. Socket.IO must be used on both sides, client and server.

The LoopBack's [Routes](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Routing.html) feature isn't applicable too because data exchange is low-level and bidirectional. Moreover, devices have two separated configurable options: **host** (domain name or IP-address) and **port**, and not any "path" option.

So I've implemented this code in `server/server.js` file in order to receive data:

```
// ...
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module) {
    app.start();

    const srvRaw = require('net').createServer(function(socket) {
      socket.on('data', function(buffer) {
        // parse received data here
      });
    });
    srvRaw.listen(PORT);
  }
});
```

The built-in `net` package is used to open dedicated port, for data exchanging purposes.

But I'm a little bit hesitating if this method is the only possible? Is there a better way to arrange low-level network negotiation, "native" for LoopBack or Express, using some built-in features?

Thanks in advance!